# Generic Procedure to generate report from browse in progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl

Procedure should handle any table linked to browse means it should be generic.
please help.

```
    /* below code is sample to Show the data in message box , 
       but only first data it is showing right now.*/

    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER hRecord  AS WIDGET-HANDLE.
    DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER hQuery  AS WIDGET-HANDLE .

    DEF VAR hFld     AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.
      DEFINE VARIABLE iCOunt AS INTEGER INITIAL 0.
      DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
      DEFINE VARIABLE j AS integer INITIAL 1.


      MESSAGE hRecord:NUM-COL VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

       DO WHILE TRUE:
                hQuery:GET-NEXT().
                iCount = iCount + 1.


                DO i = 1 TO hRecord:NUM-COL:
                       hfld = hRecord:GET-BROWSE-COL(i).
                    MESSAGE hfld:SCREEN-VALUE.

                END.
                   j = j + 1.


       END.
       MESSAGE iCount VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: You should show some effort and at least post some code that is trying to do what you want...

Comment: Is that a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a buffer field like so:

```
hfld = hRecord:GET-BUFFER-FIELD(i).
```

and then get the field's value:

```
DISPLAY hfld:BUFFER-VALUE.
```

See the docs for an explanation of what these do.